# Reading a .DatFile in

Tags: c#, console-application

Hi there i am currently trying to read in a .Dat which i am having some trouble with.

The .Date file data is formatted as follows

62720 |  |TELEPHONE  |        1000.17|P|     31040.94|       30154.88| 250

What i would like to do is to store each item in between the | into individual strings.

I have the following as my code when i run it the output to a text file each char is onto a newline. EG

6

2

7

2

0

My code as follows

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         StreamReader tbal  = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\pbrady\\Desktop\\Code\\PNLSummary\\PNLSummary\\bin\\Debug\\tbal.dat", System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        string contents = tbal.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        string[] split = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(contents, "|", RegexOptions.None);
        Console.WriteLine("*****LOADING*****");
        foreach (string s in split)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\pbrady\\Desktop\\Code\\PNLSummary\\PNLSummary\\bin\\Debug\\Test.txt", true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(s);
                Console.WriteLine(s);

            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("*****Complete*****");
    }
```

Comment: Is `|` a valid regex pattern to split on `|`? Why don't you use `contents.Split('|')`?

Comment: do you want to write each string in new line of new file?

Comment: What i would like is to have each item between | in individual datatypes so i can do calculations on them.

Comment: You have used `Regex.Split` as `string.Split` and that's why your code does not deliver what you want. `string.Split` (as suggested in the answer you got), expects the given character/string ("|" in this case); `Regex.Split` expects a pattern. `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(contents, "|", RegexOptions.None);` analyses "|" as a pattern, not as a single character.

Comment: why don't you create a data table from this dat and do the math fast as lightning? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader tbal = new StreamReader("tbal.dat");
        string contents = tbal.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        string[] split = contents.Split('|');
        Console.WriteLine("*****LOADING*****");
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Test.txt", true);
        foreach (string s in split)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(s);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        tbal.Close();
        writer.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("*****Complete*****");
    }
```

No need to provide full path. The files will create and read from debug folder of your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          String myfile= System.IO.File.ReadAllText("myfile.dat");
          String[] strWord = myfile.Split('|');
          using(System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("myfile.txt", true))
          {              
          foreach (string str in strWord)
              writer.WriteLine(str.Trim());
          }
        }
```